# Install4j: How to submit proxy settings to the autoupdater?

Tags: install4j

We will use either `ApplicationLauncher.launchApplicationInProcess` or  `ApplicationLauncher.launchApplication`.

How do we pass host, port, userid, and password to it?

Passing the information using a file would be a no-go because the password might be a user password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Proxy settings are passed to the update downloader with the arguments

```
-DproxySet=true
-DproxyHost=...
-DproxyPort=...
-DproxyAuth=true
-DproxyUser=...
-DproxyPassword=...
```

More generally, you can set installer variables in the update downloader via special arguments passed to `ApplicationLauncher`. An argument

```
-Vkey=value
```

sets the installer variable named `key` to the `value`. In all text fields of the update downloader configuration, you can use it with the syntax

```
${installer:key}
```

You can configure default values for these installer variables on the "Installer variables" tab of the update downloader configuration so that it also works when called without those arguments.

Comment: Thanks, that nails it.

Comment: Um... is proxySet required? (It is not if install4j isn't checking these system properties by itself, but lets the JDK use these.)

Comment: Yes, it's required, otherwise the other settings are not used.

Comment: Okay, let me rephrase my question: What code is interpreting these settings, that of install4j or that of the JDK? I am a bit confused because I am seeing OpenJDK properties (proxyHost - deprecated but still used) and proxySet (not used by OpenJDK, used to be in a non-Sun JDK in the 1.3 days IIRC).

Comment: All these settings are processed by install4j directly.